# VNC with screen disabled

Tags: remote-desktop

Is there a way to start a VNC session but without have the remote computer (an iMac) screen turn on ?

I tried to reduce the brightness to min on the physical machine but is not good enough.

Comment: Using the Apple Remote Desktop app, you easily can. Use the “Curtain” mode

Comment: Is but I'm try to do that from an iPhone sorry I didn't mention the IOS part.